# Understanding the Legendre transform

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In physics, I've seen the Legendre transform motivated by "changing the variable $x$ of a function $x \mapsto f(x)$ to the variable $u = \frac{df}{dx}$."

I don't quite see what that means and why the Legendre transform is the answer to this heuristic. I'd understand it as follows:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ be strictly convex and differentiable. Then for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ the slope $\frac{df(x_0)}{dx}$ is unique. We want to find a function $f^*: f'(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=f^*(\frac{df(x_0)}{dx})$ for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. In fact we can view the function $f^*$ as a function on a subset of the dual space $\mathbb{R^*}$ such that $f^*(df(x_0))=f(x_0)$.

However, this doesn't seem to capture the Legendre transform, for example by the above the Legendre transform of the exponential function should be the identity function. How can the physicists heuristic be made precise?

Answer (score 1):

The change of variable part you got right. However, the Legendre transform of $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is
$$
f^*(p)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\{xp-f(x)\}\,.
$$
Since $f$ is convex:
$$
f^*(p)=xp-f(x)\,,\text{ for }f'(x)=p\,.
$$
In other words: $f^*(p)$ is a function of $p=f'(x)$ which contains the same information as $f\,.$

> Example: $f(x)=e^x,f'(x)=e^x$ leads to $f^*(p)=xp-e^x$ with $p=e^x$, or $x=\log p\,.$ That is:
> $$
> f^*(p)=p\log p-p\,.
> $$

A marvellous paper motivating the Legendre transform in physiscs is

R.K.P. Zia, E.F. Redish, S.R. McKay, *Making Sense of the Legendre Transform*, [arXiv:0806.1147v2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1147v2.pdf), 2009.

Comment: But in the case $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$, $f^*(f'(x)) = \mathrm{e}^x \log(\mathrm{e}^x) - \mathrm{e}^x = x\,\mathrm{e}^x - \mathrm{e}^x \neq f(x)$, right?

Comment: @FeiCao : Right . Nowhere though I saw the requirement that $f^*(p)$ must equal $f(x)\,.$

Comment: @Kurt G. Since the definition of the Legendre transform of a function $f$ includes the supremum over the domain of definition, the right hand side of the expression above is just a value in the range of $xp-f(x) $, whereby $p$ also is a function of $x$. I do not understand how the left hand side, $f^*(p),$ can be a function? I will appreciate your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @user996159 In $f^*(p)=xp-f(x)$ the former variable $x$ is now a function of $p$ because it must statisfy $f'(x)=p\,.$ Therefore $f^*(p)$ is a function of $p\,.$ Study the concrete example I gave and make up a few more to get familiar with this.